# Can minor child travel out of France before applying DCEM

Tags: minors

I am an Indian, I am in France for a work and arrived last year. I had got the RP last year which is expired now and I have submitted my files for renewal of carte de Sejour. So I have a recepisse which allow me to travel outside France.

Now my family (wife and 2 year old kid) have arrived here in France, they both have type D long stay VISA valid for one year. I have validated my wife’s VISA online (required instead of applying carte de sejour).

For my daughter, I understood from sources that I need to apply for DCEM once I got my carte de sejour. Yes, I have not yet applied for DCEM for my kid yet.

Now the issue is I need to travel to India for an important family function and come back to France. I know for me and for my wife it’s ok to travel outside France and come back.

My question is whether there will be any issue for my daughter to enter into France as she don’t have DCEM (not even applied) but valid VISA.

Comment: Did you travel ? I have the same issue now, can you please tell me about your situation so that i can plan. Infact i have applied for CDEM but haven't recieved it for my 11 months kid and i had planned to go to spain, so will i be able to travel within schenzen region without DCEM ?

Comment: How many entries are on the visa?